# Ionic2 - second navigation is not worrking

Tags: angular, ionic2

Hey everyone i have a problem with my ionic2 navigation ,

This is my login.ts

```
   export class LoginPage {
      public nav:NavController = null;

        static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController]];
      }


      constructor (nav:NavController, public navParams: NavParams,) 
      {  this.nav = nav;}
       goToHome() {
          this.nav.push(HomePage);
      }
        goToAna() { 
        this.nav.push(BlankPage); 
                  }
        }
```

`goToHome()` is working well, but `goToAna()` is not working and when i click button which have `goToAna()` , `goToHome()` is stopped to navigate to HomePage...

Answer (score 1):

No need to declare `public nav: NavController = null`, if you declare it `public` in your constructor you can use it in your class as `this.nav`.

Since you can do this on every page without additional methods, I think the `return NavController` will be unneccessary.

```
export class LoginPage {

  constructor (public nav:NavController, public navParams: NavParams) { }

  goToHome() {
      this.nav.push(HomePage);
  }
  goToAna() { 
     this.nav.push(BlankPage); 
  }
}
```

If the problem still persists when using this, edit your question and add in the corresponding `HTML` file please.

Comment: İt's not  solved my problem completely but  thanks for your advice , it's help to much .

Comment: What is your problem now?

Comment: @Ivaro18 How can I pass a parameter to the `BlankPage` 
I've tried 
`this.nav.push(BlankPage, {
            categoryId:  101,
        } ); `

but did not work !?